# change vim keybindings for particular file type

Tags: vim, scripting, keymapping

I want to change some key bindings for .adb files, this is for ada. So how do I do it just for this and not for any other filetype. Also How would I disable some default features for this filetype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `ada.vim` plugin in `~/.vim/ftplugin/ada.vim` and add your `.ada` specific key bindings there.

You would also need to have `filetype plugin on` or `filetype plugin indent on` in your `.vimrc`

Comment: everything was correct except for the adb.vim, it's actually ada.vim, even though the files are .adb

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Amit's answer: Define all mappings via `:noremap <buffer> ...` and any commands with `:command -buffer`; this way, they will be scoped to the (current) buffer.

Otherwise, when you edit ada and other (say, HTML or C) files in parallel, the (global) mappings will "seep" into the other buffers, and you won't be able to define the same mapping for multiple filetypes.